# problem with Website alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, alignment

My site was all fine and properly aligned until recently. Only sometime back I integrated the thickbox onload. Since then the alignment of that particular page has gone haywire. Please help me out.

Please go through the [link](http://school.roboshaala.com) for your reference

The other pages are fine but the homepage is distorted. Please advise.

Comment: "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to school.roboshaala.com"

Do you know why? Can you show us some screenshots instead? :)

Comment: Looks okay to me. Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: check out d link now..its working..

Answer (score 2):

You put the thickbox CSS after yours.

first line in the thcickbox css :

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
```

How's your `#main` div is centered :

```
#main { background-color:; background-image: url('images/orange2.jpg')
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
body {background-color:;background-image: url('images/orange-20.jpg')} 
*{border: 0;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;}
```

The `margin: 0 auto` method is canceled because of the thickbox CSS.

2 solutions :

1. delete the 1st line of the thickbox css
2. Put your CSS after and try.

As @livetolearn said, the method you used to center is better with a `width`.

On another point, your CSS is highly optimisable. 
For example,

```
background-color:; background-image: url('images/orange2.jpg')
```

=

```
background:url('images/orange2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok from where I am. 
In FF however the page is not centered. Is that the issue?
Add:

```
#Table_01 { margin: 0 auto}
```

You do get a script error in IE
Poss "alerrt" spelling mistake?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function my_code(){
alerrt("
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css file replace this code

```
#main {
background-image: url("images/orange2.jpg");
margin: 0 auto;
width: 900px; // replace with your width
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines were in thickbox.css and they were not properly overwritten. That may be the cause

```
* {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```